# Let $X$ be separable and $\mathcal{A}$ a collection of open pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is countable.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be separable and $\mathcal{A}$ a collection of open pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is countable.

$X$ being separable implies that there exists a countable dense subset $S$ of $X$. Since $S$ is dense we have that $S \cap U \ne \emptyset$ for any $U$ open in $X$. In particular $S \cap A \ne \emptyset$ for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Does this imply that $\mathcal{A}$ is countable? If every element of $\mathcal{A}$ intersects with some countable set, then there should be only countable many elements to begin with?

Comment: The same member of $S$ could be in many open sets..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false: let $\mathcal{A}$ be all open subsets of $\Bbb R$, say (size continuum). You probably mean that $\mathcal{A}$ also consists non-empty sets and is pairwise disjoint, and then we then let $D=\{d_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ be dense and define $f: \mathcal{A} \to \Bbb N$ by $f(O) = \min\{n \mid d_n \in O\}$ which is an injection. (if $f(O_1)=f(O_2)= m$ then $d_m \in O_1 \cap O_2$ would contradict disjointness!) I pick one enumeration of the dense set to make $f$ a definite well-defined value: the set $O \cap D$ is non-empty (so has a minimum) as $D$ is dense; this avoids unnecessary use of AC. If you don't mind that we "define" $g: \mathcal{A} \to D$ by letting $g(O) \in O \cap D$ be any element. In that case we inject into $D$ instead and use $g(O_1) \in O_1, g(O_2) \in O_2$ to note the injectivity. Such a function will usually not be injective as we could pick the same element of $D$  infinitely many times in such a process: look at my example from the first line, we could pick $0 \in \Bbb Q$ for the open sets $(-1,1)$ and generally any $(a,b)$ with $a$ negative and $b$ positive, so uncountably many times.

It *is* the case that for regular $T_1$ spaces $X$ with a minimal dense set of size $\kappa$, we can have at most $2^{2^\kappa}$ many different open sets, so we *can* bound the number of open sets in a netric separable space, though not by at most countable...

Comment: Yes sorry. I forgot the pairwise disjoint argument. I’ll edit.

Comment: Why do we need the disjoint condition? If $D$ is the dense subset coming from the seperability of $X$, then we only get that $D \cap O$ is non-empty for the open sets $O$ in $\mathcal{A}$? Is it so then that each $S \cap O$ is also disjoint for different $O$’s in $\mathcal{A}$? I don’t think that’s true since $S$ can intersect multiple $O$’s with single element.

Comment: I’m still trying to figure out this $f(O)$ mapping. It looks as you’re taking the smallest $n$ such that $d_n$ is in $O$? I figure that $d_n \in O$ due to the density argument, but not sure what is the deal with the minimum.